# How to transfer Domain and Create subdomain on Azure Linux VM

Tags: linux, azure, nginx, subdomain, cname

We are in the process of moving our server to Azure Linux VM.

Currently our Linux server and NameServer is hosted at MediaTemple. On MediaTemple Server(Virtual Machine)  we’ve several applications are running as subdomain and we’re using nginx as reverse proxy server.

Now we’ve created a Virtual Machine(Linux) on azure and we got DNS : xxx.cloudapp.net.  As we’ve several application so we need several subdomain like abc.xxx.cloudapp.net, abc2.xxx.cloudapp.net ... So my question is how could we transfer our domain to azure VM and how could i create subdomain in azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently it isn't possible to create subdomains of `xxx.cloudapp.net`.

You can vote for this feature [here](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/6119382-subdomain-cloudapp-net-etc-rather-than-having-a).

But, if you have your own domain name you are able to set custom domain name for each VM.

If you are using Cloud Services [there is](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name-portal/) a good article about.

In case of single VM, do this:

Create `CNAME` records in console of your domain name registrar and bind them to `xxx.cloudapp.net`
Then you need to create nginx config file and declare each subdomain.

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    # the rest of the config
}
server {
    server_name sub1.example.com;
    # sub1 config
}
server {
    server_name sub2.example.com;
    # sub2 config
}
```

Comment: Thanks. we've done that but  when we nslookup we still getting the MediaTemple server ip got the  rather than azure VM server IP.